# How to get zoom level from a Google maps in Geocomplete jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, zooming

I'm trying to edit [this plugin](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) to get zoom level of a Google Map.

I have this piece of code which worked well on my previous Google Map init, but now it doesn't seems to do the work it should:

```
var ZoomLevel = 14; // as a Default value

google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function(ee) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'bounds_changed', function(e) {
        ZoomLevel = this.map.getZoom();
    });
});
```

That I'm adding into the: `initMap()` method of the `$.geocomplete()` plugin.

I have this `ZoomLevel` variable available through all scopes of my HTML document, but it isn't being updated at any time and those two `zoom_changed` and `bounds_changed` events aren't fired at all whether I changed bounds, zoom, marker position, etc.

I really need help on this on how to implement this into this pluggin to get the current Zoom Level.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tracking the zoomlevel you could just fetch it on demand.

```
$(<selector>).geocomplete('map').getZoom()
```

Just spent ages looking trying to work out how to access the map object and it is this simple... just ask for it!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the callbacks `this` refers to the object that triggers the event.

When I may assume that the object the first listener has been bound to is a `google.maps.Map`-instance, this should work:

```
var ZoomLevel = 14; // as a Default value

google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function(ee) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this, 'bounds_changed', function(e) {
        ZoomLevel = this.getZoom();
    });
});
```

But when the zoom changes the bounds also will change, so you may remove the inner listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function(ee) {
        ZoomLevel = this.getZoom();
});
```